# Git diff tool over several commits with other's commit inbetween

Tags: git, diff

We have a workflow where committed code needs to be reviewed by other devs. In simple cases this can be done with "git diff oldhash newhash > diff.txt" and upload that to our review board.

But is there a way to create a diff over several commits and exclude commits done in between by someone else. For example I want to create diff over mine1 to mine4 but exclude Joe's commit :

```
mine4
mine3
joe's
mine2
mine1
```

Any ideas how to do this in command line git or with some other tool?

The commits made by others affect different files than my commits, so in this case it is just about excluding changes made by others.

Comment: That does not really make sense. `mine4` is dependent on `mine3`, `joe's` and `mine2` (and `mine1` of course)

Comment: It may be dependent when looking at git’s objects but they may touch completely independent parts of the source code.

Comment: @Bombe: it may – or it may not. There's no sane representation if intermediate commits touch the same chunk of code (also, files could be moved/renamed)

Comment: Nowadays, this is much more easily done by reviewing pull/merge requests on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) (open source) or [GitHub](https://github.com/) (not open source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating a new branch combined with cherry-pick:

```
git checkout -b mine_diffs
git cherry-pick mine1
git cherry-pick mine2
git cherry-pick mine3
git cherry-pick mine4
git diff mine1_ mine4_
```

When you're done, just delete the branch. Note that the sha1 hashes will be different when diffing, which is what mine1_ and mine4_ indicates.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "over mine1 to mine4".  Diffs are always pairwise (except for mid-merge); "git diff mine1 mine4" will give you all the changes between those two trees.  Given the above example, you can get four separate patches: mine1->mine2, mine2->joes, joes->mine3, mine3->mine4.  If you did mine1->mine2, mine2->mine3, mine3->mine4 you'd still "see" joe's changes.

Perhaps what you want is (as @OleksandrKravchuk suggested) "a diff of what one would have, if one cherry-picked the changes in mine2, mine3, and mine4 into a branch that started from mine1".  In that case, you'll have to do just that: create such a branch, pick those changes to apply, and then generate the diff.

You could automate this fairly easily by creating the temporary branch and doing the sequence of "git cherry-pick"s, skipping the commit(s) you want to omit.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, maybe it is not true git way, but I would create new branch, removed unneeded commits and compared two branches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reviewing a bundle of commits as one diff is bad style: Codereview (if used) must work on single-commit level
2. You can't have "sparse" diffs
3. Maybe The Right Tools will be The Right Way? For Git it's Gerrit

Comment: Regarding 1 - There are devs who commit and push often. I guess we need to educated them to do squash rebasing then?

Comment: @PetteriHietavirta - commit often is good, but it's unrelated to CodeReview mission - "commit good code". Frequent commits is a headache of reviewer, not coder

Comment: The way we do reviews with Git is that: (1) all development happens in feature-branches (2) one developer per feature-branch (3) when branch is ready, it is squashed and re-committed so each patch represents minimal sane logical unit of change (4) branches are merged together after they pass review. See also docs on Git development process (that is, on development of Git itself).

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh - I can say nothing against your workflow: it's near ideal, but OP's situation is... welll, lets say... weaker - linear dvelopment and reviews done not for commit and not for feature (finished), but WIP

Comment: Squashing a whole feature branch into a single commit destroys valuable information and (in case of larger features) does not make the reviewer’s life any easier.

Comment: @Bombe - Squashing just **answer on different question**: not "How", but "What"