# git: cumulative diff with commit-limiting

Tags: git, diff

`git log` has some very useful [commit-limiting options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_limiting), such as `--no-merges` and `--first-parent`. I'd like to be able to use these options when generating a cumulative diff patch/stat/numstat for a range of commits.

With these commands:

```
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --patch   29665b0..0b76a27
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --stat    29665b0..0b76a27
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --numstat 29665b0..0b76a27
```

the diff is not cumulative (the changes are listed individually for each commit).

With these commands:

```
git diff --patch   29665b0..0b76a27
git diff --stat    29665b0..0b76a27
git diff --numstat 29665b0..0b76a27
```

the diff *is* cumulative, but unfortunately `git diff` doesn't support the commit-limiting options.

So what I'd like is the cumulative diff functionality of `git diff` combined with the commit-limiting functionality of `git log`.

One idea I had is to use `git log` to generate a list of commit hashes, and then somehow pipe that list to `git diff` to generate a cumulative diff of the specified commits. Something like this (obviously this method of piping hashes to `git diff` doesn't actually work):

```
git log --pretty=format:%h --first-parent --no-merges 29665b0..0b76a27 | git diff
```

where `--pretty=format:%h` outputs the hashes of the matching commits.

---

### Update

Thanks to @torek and @twalberg, I now understand `git diff`'s operation more clearly. The range syntax `29665b0..0b76a27` is indeed misleading, and I now understand that it's not actually performing a cumulative diff over a range of commits. Looking through the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), I found this:

> "diff" is about comparing two *endpoints*, not ranges, and the range notations (`<commit>..<commit>` and `<commit>...<commit>`) do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES" section in [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Taking this into account, I'll rephrase my question. With these commands:

```
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --patch   29665b0..0b76a27
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --stat    29665b0..0b76a27
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges --numstat 29665b0..0b76a27
```

the changes are listed individually for each matching commit. How can I combine those individual changes, to produce a cumulative patch/stat/numstat?

The answers to the linked [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9615200) are helpful, suggesting a solution: create a temporary branch, cherry-pick the relevant commits, and then generate the diff.

I've just posted an answer which uses this technique, but I'm still interested to know if there's a solution which doesn't require a temporary branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git diff tool over several commits with other's commit inbetween](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615200/git-diff-tool-over-several-commits-with-others-commit-inbetween)

Comment: Diffs are pairwise. To turn a popular saying around: *It's not the journey that matters; it's the destination* (and the point of origin).

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one basic misapprehension here.  Specifically, `git diff` is not really cumulative at all: instead, it's simply pairwise.

Specifically, these two commands do the same thing:

```
git diff rev1 rev2
git diff rev1..rev2
```

That is, in `git diff`, there really is no such thing as a range in the first place.

---

With that out of the way, let's take a look behind the scenes at `git log`.  What `git log` does with a range is really<sup>1</sup> to hand the range to `git rev-list`, which produces a list of every rev in the range, applying the modifiers along the way:

```
git rev-list 29665b0..0b76a27
```

spits out every rev reachable from `0b76a27` that is not also reachable from `29665b0`.  Adding `--first-parent`, `--max-parents=1` (aka `--no-merges`), and so on filters away some of the revs that would be listed here.

The final result is given back to `git log`, which then looks at each revision in the order `git rev-list` spits them out—this is also controllable via `--date-order` and `--topo-order` and so on; see the [documentation for git rev-list](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)—and shows you each log entry, perhaps along with a diff as produced by [`git diff-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html) (which for single-parent commits, compares the commit to its parent).

What you can do, then, is invoke `git rev-list` yourself, directly, and then peel off the top and bottom revisions from its output.  (In this particular case you probably want `--topo-order` too, to make sure that the last rev really is the earliest, graph-wise, regardless of dates.)  For instance, in a script:

```
#! /bin/sh
tempfile=$(mktemp -t mydiff)
trap "rm -f $tempfile" 1 2 3 15
git rev-list 29665b0..0b76a27 --first-parent --no-merges --topo-order > $tempfile
# remember that the first rev listed is the last rev in the range
last=$(head -1 $tempfile)
first=$(tail -1 $tempfile)
rm -f $tempfile # done with it, don't leave it around while showing diff
git diff $first $last
```

You can get considerably fancier by using `git rev-parse` to parse options and split them into diff options vs rev-list options, but that's way beyond what you need here.  The main thing to improve above is to get rid of the hard-coded revision-range.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some git commands *really* really do hand arguments off to `git rev-list`, as they're just shell scripts that use `git rev-list` and other git commands to handle this.  Others are built together, so that `git log` and `git rev-list` are actually a single binary, and one part hands a job off to another part, but without invoking a new program.

In any case, note that `git log master` simply hands `master` off to `git rev-list`, which produces a list of all revs reachable from the branch-label `master`.  If you add `--no-walk`, `git rev-list` produces just one rev, so that `git log` shows only that one revision.

Comment: Aside from the fact it would break a lot of pre-existing (but ill-formed) code out there, I would personally prefer that the `git` folks disallow the range notation to `git diff` (and a couple other places where it doesn't make sense) and avoid this type of confusion...

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# Create a temporary branch to mark the start of the cherry-picked commits
git branch tmpstart

# Create and checkout a temporary branch for the cherry-picked commits
git checkout -b tmpend

# Use git log to filter the range of commits with the desired
# commit-limiting options, and then cherry-pick each matching commit
git log \
    --first-parent \      # Commit-limiting
    --no-merges \         # Commit-limiting
    --reverse \           # Reverse the order (ascending chronological order)
    --pretty=format:%h \  # Output the abbreviated hash of each matching commit
    29665b0..0b76a27 \    # Range of commits
  | xargs -n 1 git cherry-pick

# Generate the patch/stat/numstat of the cherry-picked commits
git diff --patch   tmpstart tmpend
git diff --stat    tmpstart tmpend
git diff --numstat tmpstart tmpend
```

Comment: I only saw the update now...  If you only want to apply those particular commits (and then show a patch, stats, etc) you pretty much do have to do this (repeated cherry-picks).  You can improve this slightly by using `git rev-list` directly instead of `git log` here, and you can avoid the temporary branch by using the "detached HEAD" mode to build the branch, but it all comes out the same, really.